# inverted colors after suspend

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics

Often, after my computer wakes from suspend, the colors shown on the monitor are inverted (or something, it looks rather bizarre). Any idea of the cause? So far, the only fix I have is to restart the computer.

Version: 16.04 LTS

(My monitor is plugged into the) graphics card: Gallium 0.4 on AMD TURKS (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a reboot try this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart
```

If this doesnt work restart the module :

```
lsmod | grep amd               <- search for the module name 
sudo modprobe -r *module-name  <- unload the module
sudo modprobe *module-name     <- load the module
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep having the same problem. The temporary solution I have found is to enable guest account. This will allow you to switch account which then fixes the issue.